# Are all 1 dimensional Poisson manifold trivial?

Tags: geometry, differential

The title says it all. How to rigorously prove or disprove that all poisson brackets on C^{inf}(R) are trivial ?

Comment: people think it is obvious and don't question themselves the post was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson bracket on functions corresponds to the Lie bracket of the associated Hamiltonian vector fields. On a $1$-dimensional vector space, the Lie bracket is trivial, because 
$$
\{x,y\}=-\{y,x\},
$$ 
so that it follows that $\{\lambda x,\mu x\}=\lambda \mu \{x,x\}=0$.

Comment: Hi Dietrich, I understand that the bracket has to be trivial on polynomials in x but how does it imply that it is for arbitrary functions ?